# Are there any performance penalties to setting an sqlalchemy table to autoload as opposed to coding out the schema?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there any reason I shouldn't simply set every table to auto-load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure there is during the configuration phase, as required schema needs to be loaded from the database. But this is more than acceptable as this is done only once during the start-up.